# SQL - combine UNION and SORT BY for several statements

Tags: sql, select

I have a list of 100.000 User which I need to query for email domain and score for 10000 each. It is needed to take all with score 4 first. If there are not enough go to score 3 and so on.Meaning a priorization query The solution I received is working fine for one statement

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * 
FROM [table] 
WHERE Email like '%@test.com' and score in ( 1, 2, 3, 4) 
order by score desc
```

as soon as I am trying to use that for multiple statements I receive invalid syntax errors:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM 
[table] 
WHERE Email like '%@test.com'and score in ( 1, 2) 
order by score desc 
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM
[table] WHERE Email like '%@test2.com' and score in ( 1, 2, 3, 4)
order by score desc
```

I would need to be able to add as many EMAILS as I want. Help is higly appreciated :)

Comment: Remove order by from first query and add order by at the end of the query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hello, it is integrated into Salesforce and based on SQL Server 2005 capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the order by from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

just leave the order by  at the bottom     and remove the order by for the others

```
  SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM [table] 
  WHERE Email like '%@test.com' and score in ( 1, 2) 
  UNION 
  SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [table] 
  WHERE Email like '%@test2.com' and score in ( 1, 2, 3, 4) 
  order by score desc
```

otherwise if you need the ordered  values in each select the build separated select uing ()

```
  select TOP 11000 * from 
  (SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM [table] 
  WHERE Email like '%@test.com' and score in ( 1, 2) 
  order by score desc ) t1
  UNION 
  select * from 
  ( SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [table] 
  WHERE Email like '%@test2.com' and score in ( 1, 2, 3, 4) 
  order by score desc ) t2
  ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: If I do that it just orders the selection of the second statement and leaves the first one without priorization.

Comment: the order  by at the end must work on all the result for the Union non only  with the second part  ..  the order by is applied  at the union not at the last select  .. hope is clear ..

Comment: anyway i have update the answer with a suggestion for you need .. hope is useful

Comment: thanks for your update. if I try your suggestion the following notification appears: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

The SQL support for the Query Activity is based on SQL Server 2005 capabilities. That might be important to say.

Comment: Update: seems to work if I leave away the last "order by"